# Can Ransomware migrate from an infected PC to uninfected Linux computers on a network?

Tags: linux, networking, security, virus, malware

My roommate's company was recently hit by a comprehensive Ransomware attack and she has been working from home via our home network.  All the other computers in our house other than her work machine are Linux-based, but I am unclear as to how the malicious software propagates.  Am I at risk of having MY system compromised because I've been using the same router?  Will Ransomware that targets a PC be able to also infect and target a Linux OS machine?  I don't believe we've shared any USB disks or that such "transmission" recently, though perhaps we have.

Any and all help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Apologies if this question seems basic but I did a fair bit of searching for answers to this specific issue and found a lot about "Linux is vulnerable" and of course on PCs that were infected, but not on the vectors of transmission.

Lastly, am I able to use any Linux tools to determine if there's been an infection?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The answer is we don't know... Is it possible? Yes. But it is highly unlikely... About as likely as winning the lottery or being struck by lightning while being bitten by a shark. Attacks like this are purpose built, so although it is possible that it could infect a Linux PC, chances are good it cannot. Without specific details on the attack vector, it is impossible to say with 100% certainty.

Comment: Yes; WannaCry was ransomware that would infect any vulnerable device on the network it could communicate with and encrypt any that drive accessible by that machine.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I understand that it's "possible" but I meant more about likelihood.  My understanding is that (generally) a virus that infects a PC isn't going to infect a Linux machine but as these things get more sophisticated...who knows.  All I know is that the attack was via a cloud connection.  Not sure beyond that.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for this info.  I just looked up WannaCry and it appears to have only worked on Windows machines...not Linux OS.  This is a bit of a relief.

Comment: MacOS and Linux have had their own share of infections that could spread by themselves (worms). WannaCry is just a single example that exists.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you again, yes, I understand but I'm trying to see if there is a specific threat out there that will leap from a PC to a Linux machine and infect both.  This attack has apparently only infected Windows PCs...thus far.  I'm trying to figure out if I should stay up all night burning everything valuable onto DVDs or if I'm "probably" safe since my machines are Linux OS.  I do understand that both systems can be self-propagating.  What interests me is the chance they can cross over or work on both OS types.

Comment: Some of the ransomware attacks are active attacks driven by people, not software.  If they thought infecting the computers at your house was worth their time, it could happen no matter what they are running.  Keep everything patched and don't have open file shares, and you at least make it harder.

Comment: @confused Linux system are als attacked, especially considering that most IoT device and a lot of printers (both categories that often don't get security updates) base on Linux and thus are easy attack targets. Linux desktop and server are usually less vulnerable but if a ranswomware gang has picked your network as target they usually find a way to also infect such system if not using a vulnerability then may be with social engineering or just by sniffing entered passwords.